# How can I make my Syncfusion cardlayout honor my validations and not advance?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am somewhat new to the Syncfusion library and I want to use a Syncfusion element called CardLayout where I put cardviews and use an event called VisibleCardIndexChanged but what I want is to validate that the current card is answered with the fields within it but not how to do that part.

```
private async void layoutCard_VisibleCardIndexChanged(object sender, VisibleCardIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{


    /**radio Groups **/
    SfRadioButton radio = groupCalidad.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioApp = groupApp.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioDiseno = groupDiseno.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioBeneficio = groupBeneficio.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioLogin = groupLogin.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioPerfiles = groupPerfiles.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioPanel = groupPanel.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioIdiomas = groupIdiomas.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioEstado = groupEstado.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioMantenimiento = groupMantenimientoRb.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioDoc = groupDocumentacion.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioTipo = groupTipo.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioEspecial = groupEspecializada.CheckedItem;
    SfRadioButton radioDispo = groupDispo.CheckedItem;

    /** Check Buttons **/



    int indice = layoutCard.VisibleCardIndex+1;

    switch (indice)
    {
        case 19:
            if (radio == null)
            {
                return;
               //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);

            }
            break;
        case 18:
            if (radioApp == null)
            {
                return;
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 17:
            if (radioDiseno == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 16:
            if (radioBeneficio == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 15:
            if (radioLogin == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 14:
            if (radioPerfiles == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 13:
            if (radioPanel == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 12:
            if (radioIdiomas == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 11:
            if (radioEstado == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 10:
            if (chkNoti.IsChecked == false && chkGeo.IsChecked == false && chkPagoLinea.IsChecked == false && chkLogotipo.IsChecked == false &&
                chkVideo.IsChecked == false && chkStream.IsChecked == false && chkChat.IsChecked == false && chkPaises.IsChecked == false &&
                chkSensores.IsChecked == false && chkBusqueda.IsChecked == false && chkEncript.IsChecked == false && chkInteraccion.IsChecked == false
                && chkStats.IsChecked == false)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(6);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            if (radioMantenimiento == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            if (radioDoc == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if (radioTipo == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            if (radioEspecial == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            if (chkCamaras.IsChecked == false && chkGPS.IsChecked == false && chkBarras.IsChecked == false && chkHuellas.IsChecked == false &&
                chkMicrofono.IsChecked == false && chkImpresora.IsChecked == false && chkRaspberry.IsChecked == false && chkOtros.IsChecked == false)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (chkRedes.IsChecked == false && chkERP.IsChecked == false && chkCRM.IsChecked == false && chkPuntoVenta.IsChecked == false &&
                chkOtroExterno.IsChecked == false)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (radioDispo == null)
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (txaRequisitos.Text == null || txaRequisitos.Text.Equals("") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txaRequisitos.Text))
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frEmail.Value.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmPhone.Value.ToString())
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmEmpresa.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmLegal.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmEmpleados.Value.ToString())
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmExperiencia.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmPais.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmFecha.Date.ToString())
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmHora.Time.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmCal.Value.ToString()) || (rbtZoom.IsChecked == false && rbtMeet.IsChecked == false && rbtOtro.IsChecked == false))
            {
                //e.cancel = true;
                Error.Text = "Error, No se puede avanzar, falta contestar";
                await Error.FadeTo(0, 500);
                await Error.FadeTo(1, 300);
                await scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0.0, 800, true);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Error.Text = "";
                await BarraProgreso(5);
                Calculo(indice);
                btnCotizar.IsVisible = true;
            }
            break;
        case 0:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }



}
```

I tried with e.cancel but that only works with VisibleCardIndexChanging but with that event an action is executed several times and I only want it to be executed once if the form of each card is validated or not and with the VisibleCardIndexChanging event several executions are made times what makes my calculations double or triple.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the reported query. You can skip the operation in the VisibleCardIndexChanging event when execute more than one time by adding the condition that the VisibleCardIndex is not equal to the previous card index as in the code below.

```
private int previousCardIndex = -1;

private void SfCardLayout_VisibleCardIndexChanging(object sender, VisibleCardIndexChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (cardLayout.VisibleCardIndex != previousCardIndex)
    {
        previousCardIndex = cardLayout.VisibleCardIndex;

         // your code.
    }
}
```

We will analyze this problem internally on our side. Meanwhile, you can use the above solution.